# How do I remove the root element of my Jetty webapp url?

Tags: java, url, maven, jetty

I am running a Java webapp (let's call it mywebapp).

Currently I access my page in this webapp by pointing locally to:

```
http://localhost:9000/mywebapp/mystuff
```

However, I need  to access it using:

```
http://localhost:9000/mystuff
```

How can I do this?  I've tried messing with some confs, but to no avail...

This is my current root.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/root</Set>
    <Set name="war">
        <SystemProperty name="app.webapps.path"/>/mywebapp.war
    </Set>
</Configure>
```

Also tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
    <Set name="war">
        <SystemProperty name="app.webapps.path"/>/mywebapp.war
    </Set>
</Configure>
```

I'm using Maven - not sure if that may be making the difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to set your context path to `"/"` you'll want to use a Context deployment.
Note: You MUST specify a context path string for path spec mapping reasons.  An empty context path string `""` is only valid as a mapping result from requests to the context root. See Section 12.2 of the servlet spec)

In Jetty 7.x, the context path assignment is handled by the AppProviders assigned to the DeploymentManager.

By default, on the Jetty Distribution, ***both*** the WebAppProvider and ContextProvider are enabled.  This is important to know later, as it will influence your decisions on where to put the mywebapp.war file.

See the `${jetty.home}/start.ini` file, and you'll see that it contains both the references to `etc/jetty-webapps.xml` and `etc/jetty-contexts.xml`

WebAppProvider's role is to pay attention to the `${jetty.home}/webapps/` directory for any deployable applications (such as *.war) and deploy them onto a context of the same name as the filename.  In other words `${jetty.home}/webapps/MyApp-2.4.war` is deployed into the context `"/MyApp-2.4"`.  There is also the special "root.war" reserved word that will deploy into the context `"/"`.  While this is the easiest deployment mechanism, it sacrifices control over the deployment specifics.

ContextProvider's role is to pay attention to the `${jetty.home}/contexts/` directory for any jetty-xml formatted deployable contexts.   This deployment mechanism gives you the maximum control over the deployment, the xml file can control anything that is ultimately resolved to a [org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler.html) base class, of which [WebAppContext](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html) (wars / servlets / etc) are part of. 
The most common use is to specify a WebAppContext based xml file, and control things such as what files and directories make up the web application, what temporary directory to use, and even what Context Path to use.

What you'll want to do is to is:

1. Make sure your ContextProvider based deployments are enabled in the start.ini (make sure that `etc/jetty-context.xml` is present)
2. Create a [`${jetty.home}/contexts/mywebapp.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/test-jetty-webapp/src/main/config/contexts/test.xml) that declares the `<Set name="contextPath">/</Set>` option.
3. If you have the `etc/jetty-webapps.xml` present in your start.ini, *do not* put your mywebapp.war in `${jetty.home}/webapps` as that will cause the WebAppProvider to also deploy the same webapp and confusing your deployment.

Finally, you can see how this is done in the [jetty distribution](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-distribution/) itself, just open the `${jetty.home}/contexts/test.xml` and look around.  You'll see that it loads the `${jetty.home}/webapps/test.war` via the ContextProvider's use of the `${jetty.home}/contexts/test.xml` into the `"/"` context path.

Another note, look at the logs.

2012-01-13 13:56:28.779:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_-any-/webapp/},/home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/jetty-distribution-7.6.0.RC3/webapps/test.war

That tells me that WebAppContext was

- Started on `{/,` (the root Context Path)
- Using the temp/work directory `file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_-any-/webapp/`
- Using the web application specified in `/home/joakim/code/jetty/distros/jetty-distribution-7.6.0.RC3/webapps/test.war`.

**Update:** clarifying the statement about the empty context path.

Comment: How is an empty context path "effectively forbidden in servlet spec 3.0"? Can you quote a specific reference to this effect?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, I still don't get it so I filed https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417730. NOTE: I read section 12.2 of the specification but I see nothing there forbidding the use of a context path of `""` or `"/"` (I assume you're referring to both cases).

Comment: Is it possible to have deployment to the root (/) and the application name context paths on the same time?

Answer (score 1):

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deploy_Web_Applications:

> If the webapp is called root.war or the directory is called root/ then
>   Jetty deploys it at the / context.

PS: I've never used Jetty, and it took me 3 seconds to find with Google.

Comment: Thanks... My IS dept isn't happy with calling our wars root.xml, and setting the path to /root didn't work. (I had also tried google...)

Comment: See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/SetContextPath. set the context path to / (or the empty string, I don't know) in this file.

Comment: Nice try but this is not an answer, this is just pointing to a resource I also found with google in only 2 seconds. I would need stackoverflow to dumb it down, not act smart by pointing to bad documentation without clear examples. (the link's examples are not clear enough).